# Why do we call the fully connected layers in CNN "the Top Layers"?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, terminology

I've read some papers about Convolutional Neural Networks and found that almost all the papers call the fully connected layers in a normal CNN "the Top Layers".

However, as is shown in the most papers, the typical CNNs have  a top-down structure and the fully connected layers, which are usually followed by a softmax classifier, are put in the bottom of the network. So, why do we call them the "Top layers"? Is this a kind of convention or there is some other considerations I don't know?

Comment: I found this question helpful while programming a reproduction of a paper's CNN and then improving it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's just a matter of taste, but saying the "top layers" correlates with the notion of "head" in the neural networks. People say "classification head" and "regression head" meaning the output layer of the neural network (this terminology is used in [`tf.estimator.Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator), also see some discussions [here](https://adeshpande3.github.io/adeshpande3.github.io/The-9-Deep-Learning-Papers-You-Need-To-Know-About.html) and [here](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-optimize-regression-with-deep-neural-network)). If you see it this way, the layers just before the head are the *top* ones, while the input layers are the *bottom*. Anyway, you should double check what particular layers are meant when they are referred to as "top".

Answer (score 12):

There is a good reason to distinguish them from rest of the layers, well beyond "convention".

CNN have many layers, each looking at different level of abstraction. It starts from very simple shapes and edges and later learns e.g. to recognise eyes and other complex features. In a typical setting the top layer will be one or two layers deep fully connected network. Now, the important piece: the top layer weights are most directly influenced by the labels. That is the layer that effectively makes a decision (or rather produce probabilities) that something is a cat.

Imagine now that you want to build your own model to recognise cute cats, not just cats. If you start from scratch, you have to provide large volume of training examples so that the model learns to recognise what constitutes a cat in the first place. Often you don't have the luxury of that amount of data or enough processing power. What you might do instead:

1. Take an existing, well-performing model with already learned weights on e.g. ImageNet. There are some amazing, state-of-the-art models out there, trained on millions of images. You will hardly be able to beat winners of ILSVRC competition.
2. Remove the top layer. You are not interested in all the labels that the original model has learned.
3. Fix the weights of the model you have borrowed. It's already excellent at recognising cats and you don't want to screw weights by training.
4. Add your own top layer and train the model on cute cats.

The idea behind is that the original model has learned to recognise generic features in CNN layers and these can be reused. The top layer goes already beyond generic, into specific pieces that are in the training set - and these can be discarded. No cute cats there.